# why is my jquery UI datepicker not defaulting to english

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

i basically copied the code [from here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) but when i tested my site i saw this:

[alt text http://img148.imageshack.us/img148/8167/datepicker.png](http://img148.imageshack.us/img148/8167/datepicker.png)

any idea why i am not getting an english calendar

Comment: Because you computer locale is different

Comment: cOmrade is saying that your computer's date/time/language/country is set to Chinese perhaps and based on that the calendar is displaying the text.

Comment: @Aseem Gautam - no this is not the case

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[From the jQuery UI docs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker), it's based on your computer's locale as c0mrade said in comments, but you can override:

**Localization**

> Datepicker provides support for localizing its content to cater for different languages and date formats. Each localization is contained within its own file with the language code appended to the name, e.g. jquery.ui.datepicker-fr.js for French. These files are loaded after the main datepicker code. They add their settings to the set of available localizations and automatically apply them as defaults for all instances.
>
> The $.datepicker.regional attribute holds an array of localizations, indexed by language code, with '' referring to the default (English). Each entry is an object with the following attributes: closeText, prevText, nextText, currentText, monthNames, monthNamesShort, dayNames, dayNamesShort, dayNamesMin, weekHeader, dateFormat, firstDay, isRTL, showMonthAfterYear, and yearSuffix.
>
> You can restore the default localizations with:

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['']);
```

> And can then override an individual datepicker for a specific locale:

```
$(selector).datepicker($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
```

Comment: @Nick Craver:  i already have this line:

`$('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy' });`

how would i combine the two ?

Comment: @oo - Just call `$.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['']);` before it, setting the region for all your date pickers...you can place any of the 2 character strings are the param at the end, look at the source of this, dropdown at the end to get a list of options:  view-source:http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/localization.html

Comment: I tried this for Australian English but it still shows the US date format         $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['']);
        $("#_ctl0__ctl0_Body_Body_datepicker").datepicker($.datepicker.regional['en-AU']);

Comment: FYI, don't forget to include the translation file that can be found  in `development-bundle/ui/i18n/` from the custom build. Without it, the regional will always revert to default.